# How to start local host in windows service

Tags: c++, windows-services

[I followed this link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CppWindowsService-cacf4948#content)How to start a local host in windows service, i have a client application to hit that particular local server

i have followed may links to create a windows service,but where to add the extra code for example start local host.

i am creating lambda c++ rest , that i am listening in local host, when request comes for particular lambda i have to serve that.

Regards
vinod

Comment: What do you mean by "start"? What do you mean by "local host"? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CppWindowsService-cacf4948#content followed this link